# Trigger a Loop to pause and continue when space bar is pressed

Tags: ruby, loops, while-loop

I want to pause the running loop when i hit <kbd>space</kbd> and resume it again on doing so. How do i do it?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rest-client'

URL="some url here"
data1 = 0
data2 = 0
sign = ["up","down","equal"]
i=3

while true
    response = RestClient.get(URL)
    arr = (response.body).split(/"/)
    data2=arr[9].to_i
    if data2>data1
        i = 0
    elsif data2<data1
        i = 1
    else data2 == data1
        i = 2
    end
    puts "#{arr[9]}   #{sign[i]}"
    data1=arr[9].to_i                       #marker<<<---Here
end
```

Simpler saying i want the loop to come to the marker and not run again till <kbd>space</kbd> is pressed.

**Edit**
I tried putting a `puts` there but obviously it pauses there and waits for me to give an input every time. Please try to make things as less complex as possible. I am kind of a beginner.

Comment: @sawa How do i pause this loop when i press space

Comment: `loop do ... end` is preferable to `while true ... end`.

Comment: Yes but how do i accomplish what I desire?

Answer (score 1):

Use threads? This is not a direct answer but will give you a picture of how to use them.

```
$key_hit = false
t1 = Thread.new{

loop{
        puts "Hello"
        break if $key_hit
    }
}

t2 = Thread.new {
    x = gets
    $key_hit = true
}
t1.join
t2.join

puts "Done, exiting"
```

Comment: Do try and avoid using global variables in such a casual way. The indentation on this is also all over the place.

Comment: This isnt working bro. Did you even try running your own code? It just keeps on printing `hello` and doesnt stop at all.

Comment: Did you try hitting a enter to trigger the gets? I never said this was the exact code. Read the code @Rishav

Comment: @av501 I did hit enter. I read the code. And i know it isnt the exact code. But your code just prints `hello` and on pressing enter it leaves a line and continues the job. There is no pause and no wait for another enter to resume.

Comment: Not the experience on my PC @Rishav Cleanly exits on enter here. what platform are you running this on?  In any case, take a look at the idea behind it. No one is going to give you exact code. Use the principle behind the threads to do the job. One thread can do work other can accept input.

Comment: I dont want the exact code nor I asked for it. I tried running the code. And yes it does exits on key hit but it doesnt resume on key hit again.  PS earlier it didnt even stop because I didnt write the line ` $key_hit = true`. My bad. Apologies.